# Stopping an audio in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I played an audio with the following code:

```
var audio;
function playAudio(y){
    audio = new Audio(y);
    audio.play();
}
```

Now I want to stop this audio from another function. I cannot find any audio.stop(). Please note I want to stop not pause.

Comment: Use `.pause()`, optionally setting `.src=""` to kill any active streaming,

Comment: along with what @AlexK. said and setting `currentTime` to 0.

Comment: From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/gg589489%28v=vs.85%29.aspx): "When a file is first loaded, the paused property returns true (playback is paused) even though the pause method has not explicitly been called." implying that audio is never in a _stopped_ state, it can only ever be paused - hence the reason for there being no `.stop()` method.

Comment: Thanks Alex and White.